# run migration for different database connections

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have two mysql connection and i want to migrate specific database with `php artisan migrate --database=databasename` and when i ran command `php artisan migrate --database=mysql_test` connection that it database is different . i give error `Base table or view already exists`. there are two separate databases. what is the problem?

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => null,
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => "BDA",
            'username' => "root",
            'password' => "@Sina@abc123",
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
//            'engine' => null,
            'engine' => "InnoDB",
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
    
'mysql_test' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => null,
            'host' => "127.0.0.1",
            'port' => "3306",
            'database' => "BDB",
            'username' => "root",
            'password' => "@Sina@abc123",
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
//            'engine' => null,
            'engine' => "InnoDB",
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a fresh project?

Comment: @apokryfos it seem working in fresh project . it is weird . what is the problem

Comment: @connectaadmin could be one of the table on migration already exists, instead could you please try `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` and see if its working. #CAUTION: only try this on test database or instead you can try by creating a new database `BDC` and  updating the `database => B2C` on mysql_test

Comment: I read the code a bit and *I think* it may not work if you have any database operations that run in a service provider since that will connect to the default database first and the connection will just be reused if it's already connected regardless of setting. If you can confirm this is the case maybe you can raise an issue in https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues since I don't think this should be happening

Answer (score 0):

If you mean using a different database connection, this solution exists in the docs:

```
protected $connection = 'mysql_test';
```

add connection in migration file before up method.

Prefer Laravel doc for more info.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#setting-the-migration-connection